# カテゴリーのホテル一覧ページで、カテゴリーAがカテゴリーのホテルに属しているか確認して表示したいです。

Tags: php, wordpress

こんにちは。
wordpressを使用してホテルのウェブサイトを制作しています。

＊＊＊実現したいこと＊＊＊
ホテルの検索ページでドロップダウンを使用して目的地と旅行テーマでフィルターをかけられるページを作成しています。
カテゴリー”ホテル”の投稿記事に、カテゴリー”旅行テーマ”が登録されているか確認して、その登録されている旅行テーマ又は目的地のみを表示したいです。

例としてカテゴリーは以下です。
カテゴリー　ホテル(id=18)
カテゴリー 目的地(id=15) => 子カテゴリー ”日本=>東京”、”イギリス=>ロンドン”、”フランス＝>パリ”
カテゴリー 旅行テーマ(id=2) => 子カテゴリー　”ショッピング”、”食べ歩き”、”ロマンティック”

記事Aは、ホテル、旅行テーマの食べ歩き、目的地は日本=>東京
記事Bは、ホテル、旅行テーマのロマンティック、目的地はフランス＝>パリ

この場合、旅行テーマのドロップダウンの選択肢には、食べ歩きとロマンティックのみを表示させ、目的地の選択肢には日本とフランスのみを表示させたいのですが、どうやってcategory.php上でそれぞれのカテゴリーを取得したらいいのか全く分からず手が動かない状態です。目的地と旅行テーマの子カテゴリーには、たくさん他にも登録されています。

＊＊＊現状＊＊
下記のコードだと全てのカテゴリーが表示され、フィルターできていない状態です。

```
<!--category-18.php-->
<!--目的地のカテゴリー取得-->
$destinations = get_categories(array(
   'parent' => 15,
   'hide_empty' => 1,
   'hierarchical' => 0
));
foreach ($destinations as $dest) : ?>
<option class="category__filter__dropdown" value="<?php echo $dest->term_id; ?>" data-destination="<?php echo $dest->term_id; ?>">
       <?php echo $dest->name;>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!--旅行テーマのカテゴリー取得-->
$travel_topics = get_categories(array(
       'parent' => 2,
       'hide_empty' => 1,
       'hierarchical' => 0
));
foreach ($travel_topics as $cat) : ?>
<option class="category__filter__dropdown" value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>" data-reisethema="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>">
       <?php echo $cat->name;>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

もしアドバイスいただけたらとても助かります。よろしくお願いします。
[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/mro8siju16njae)にも同じ質問をしましたが、まだコメントをもらっていないのでここでも質問を投稿しました。

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと質問の内容が把握しきれなかったのですが、なんとなくですみませんが投稿してみます。
検索って、いろいろ関わってくるので大変ですよね。
`get_categories`で取得するカテゴリーで、'include'で必要なものだけにするか、不要なものを`exclude`で除外するといいんじゃないでしょうか？
https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/get_categories

無数にカテゴリーを作ってあるようですので、一旦は`get_categories`で全部カテゴリー情報を取得して、そいつから「これに含まれているカテゴリなのでいらない、これもいらない」とか不要なものを引っこ抜いたりしていくのかな。

とにかく、必要なカテゴリーのIDを配列で作れたらいいですね。
そしたら'include'で指定してあげれば自由に取り出せると思います。
工夫してやってみるといいんじゃないでしょうか。